# Vector is, the other isn't persisting in Visual Studio Unit Testing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

In my C++ library, I have two globally defined vectors.

```
vector< vector<float> > history;
vector< vector<float> > graph;
```

I am new to unit testing and was trying to work out whether these globally defined vectors persist from test to test. I had two identical tests for history, one after the other, the first one passed, the second failed. When I added a `history.clear()` at the end of the first test, the problem stopped and both passed. So this made me think that they clearly were persisting. However, In one test, I call the `drawGraph` routine below and then check the size of it - it has been populated. However, in the next sequential test `graph.size()`equals zero. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and it's built in unit testing framework. Why is this?

```
void populateArray(int input, int time) {
    values.push_back(time);
    values.push_back(input);
    if (history.size() > 0) {
        values.push_back(values[0] - history.back()[0]);
        values.push_back(values[1] - history.back()[1]);
        values.push_back(values[3] / values[2]);
    }

    history.push_back(values);
    values.clear();
};

void drawGraph() {
    float m, c, j, x1, x2;
    graph.clear();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < history.size() - 1) {
        j = i + 1;
        x1 = history[i][0];
        x2 = history[j][0];
        m = history[j][3] / history[j][2];
        c = history[i][1] - m*x2;
        i++;
        values.push_back(x1);
        values.push_back(x2);
        values.push_back(m);
        values.push_back(c);
        graph.push_back(values);
        values.clear();
    }
};
```

Comment: I assume `values` is another global :(

Comment: Can you show the test that has graph.size() equal zero?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Unit tests and globals are from different universes.